# Rename app.config to dllname.dll.config

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll, app-config

I have a class library, which has an app.config and when built it put the app.config along with the dll in the output directory I have chosen.

I don't want it to be name app.config though, if I have another component that has it's own dll, I can see confusion happening.

I've been looking at another project, that does exactly that, but I can't see why it outputs dllname.dll.config and mine always app.config.

Any ideas?

Thx

Answer (score 6):

You probably have set the `Copy to output directory` setting of the `app.config`.

BUT: In a class library, an `app.config` is useless.

Note, that you can only have *one* config file per application. The configuration is being read (at execution time) from `<executing assembly file name> + ".config"`.

Comment: well in this case the output is stuck in a directory which, using MEF is picked up and injected into another app.

Comment: What is the "Copy to output directory" and the "Build action" setting of your app.config?

Comment: Build Action = None.  Copy to output Directory = Do not copy.
Which is the same as the demo project I am looking at that does output as dllname.dll.config - it's voodoo!!

Comment: Hmmm, ... this should work. Do you have a second .config file in this project? Is the app.config directly under the project node?

Comment: And you have the file `app.config` in the output dir? If yes, delete the bin/ directory and do a rebuild.

Comment: yeah tried that already.  I'm now actually outputting to another location.

Comment: OK. out of ideas. create a new class library, copy and include all files of the old project.